# Como adicionar item na API

Tags: html, angularjs, mongodb

Estou fazendo um forum básico só para teste, estou usando o `mongo` e `postman` para adicionar algumas coisas para teste. Porem agora, quero que a partir da pagina, eu envie tais dados. 
Uso a `http://localhost:3000/topico/cadastrar` para adicionar os itens.

Segue os codigos feito ate agora com algumas modificações, usando como exemplo nesse site http://tableless.com.br/criando-uma-aplicacao-simples-com-angularjs/

```
$scope.adicionaItem = function () {
  $scope.itens.push({titulo: $scope.item.titulo, assunto: $scope.item.assunto, descricao: $scope.item.descricao});
  //$scope.item.produto = $scope.item.quantidade = '';
  toastr.success("Tópico Adicionado com Sucesso");
};

describe('Lista Compras Unitário', function () {
  describe('ListaComprasController', function () {
    beforeEach(function () {
      this.$scope = {};
      this.controller = new ListaComprasController(this.$scope);
    });

    it('deve criar "itens" com 2 ítens', function () {
      expect(this.$scope.itens.length).toBe(2);
    });

    describe('adicionaItem', function () {
      it('deve adicionar um novo ítem à lista com dados do escopo', function () {
        this.$scope.item = {};
        this.$scope.item.titulo;
        this.$scope.item.assunto;
        this.$scope.item.descricao;
        this.$scope.adicionaItem();
        expect(this.$scope.itens.length).toBe(3);
        expect(this.$scope.itens[2].titulo).toBe('Carne');
        expect(this.$scope.itens[2].assunto).toBe(5);
        expect(this.$scope.itens[2].descricao).toBeFalse;
      });
    });
  });
});
```

**html:**

```
<form class="form-horizontal">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="titulo" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Titulo</label>
    <div class="col-sm-8">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="titulo" placeholder="Titulo da sua questão, seja especifico" ng-model=" item.titulo" required>
    </div></div>

    <div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-2 control-label" for="selectbasic">Assunto:</label>
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <select id="tipos" name="" class="form-control" ng-model=" item.assunto" required>
      <option value="ensino">Ensino</option>
      <option value="saude">Saúde</option>
        <option value="trabalho">Mercado de Trabalho</option>
      <option value="lazer">Lazer</option>
      <option value="trabalho">Compras</option>
      <option value="outros">Outros</option>     
    </select>
  </div>
</div>  

      <div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-2 control-label" for="textarea"></label>
  <div class="col-md-7">
    <textarea class="form-control" id="descricao" name="descricao" rows=5 ng-model=" item.descricao" required></textarea>
  </div>
</div>
      <br>
      <center><button type="submit" class="btn btn-info ng-click="adicionaItem()"> Criar Tópico</button></center>
```

Comment: Olá Mayla, poderia informar o problema?

Comment: Olá Hiago, então, não sei como/onde colocar o localhost para enviar os dados que eu digitar na pagina ir para API

Comment: vc quer inserir 1 item e enviar, ou quer preencher um vetor para enviar?

Comment: para chamar a api vc vai precisar usar o $http https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http

Comment: Enviar os itens do topico (titulo, assunto e descricao). Vou dar uma olhada no link

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Primeiro na sua controller você deve instanciar o parametro $http do angular, assim:

```
function ListaComprasController($scope, $http) {
```

No seu método adiciona item, você inclui uma chamada para sua api. Até então está apenas carregando os valores a $scope.itens.

```
$scope.adicionaItem = function () {
    $scope.itens.push({titulo: $scope.item.titulo, assunto: $scope.item.assunto, descricao: $scope.item.descricao});

var rota = 'topico/cadastrar' //caminho da sua api;
$http({
        url: rota,
        method: "POST",
        data: {itens: $scope.itens},
     }).then(function successCallback(response) {
        toastr.success("Tópico Adicionado com Sucesso");
     }, function errorCallback(response) {
        console.log(response);
    });
    //$scope.item.produto = $scope.item.quantidade = '';
};
```

Comment: Olá Debora, muito obrigada pela resposta! Deu certo, mas o único problema é que na lista (lista) e no postman é como se eu não tivesse cadastrado os itens. Só está pegando o id do tópico, mas não os itens do forum. O que poderia ser? Desde já agradeço

Comment: Débora, descobri o que faltava, obrigada pela ajuda!